# Creating Virtual Network in multiregion and Created Azure LB for Loadbalancing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to create Virtual Network in multiregion and Created Azure LB for Loadbalancing in Azure Cloud. It looks like we can loadbalance only same availability set VMs. Can we use Azure LB to load balance a multi region virtual network VMs?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of multiple-region virtual networks. VNet is scoped to a single region/location.

If you want to load balancer multi-region VMs, you can look at Cross-region load balancer (**Preview**). In this case, Azure Standard Load Balancer supports cross-region load balancing.

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/cross-region-overview